# IntelliSense "Implement interface through private field" adds unnecessary cast

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have something like the following:

```
public interface A {
    int Foo();
}
public class B : A {
    public int Foo() { return 5; }
}
public class C : A {
    private B bar;
}
```

This won't compile, and Visual Studio puts a red line under `C`; this is expected. One of the suggested solutions is `Implement interface through 'bar'`. When you click on that, Visual Studio fills out `C` like so:

```
public class C : A {
    private B bar;
    public int Foo() { return ((A) bar).Foo() }
}
```

That cast is totally unnecessary. I could manually remove it, but in my actual code, `A` has dozens of methods and is constantly changing; it would be nice if every time it changed, I could update `C` in one click without the unnecessary casts. In my situation, it would be better if IntelliSense filled it like this:

```
public class C : A {
    private B bar;
    public int Foo { return bar.Foo(); }
}
```

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to do that instead?

Comment: You know the cast is unnecessary, but the compiler can't guarantee that. What if B was implemented with a explicit interface like `public class B : A { public int Foo() {return -1;} int A.Foo() { return 5; } }`, not having the cast to `A` will cause `C` to return `-1` instead of `5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast is required as this refactoring essentially creates proxy for the interface and exposing methods of actual interface is important part of it. Without cast you may either call wrong method or fail to compile altogether.

Sample where code will have different result:

```
public class B : A
{
    int A.Foo() { return 5; }
    public int Foo() { return 42; }
}
public class C : A
{
    private B bar = new B();
    public int Foo() { 
        return bar.Foo();  // returns 42 as it calls public method of B
        return ((A) bar).Foo(); // return 5 as it calls interface A imlplementation
    }
}
```

Sample that fails to compile without cast:

```
public class B : A
{
    int A.Foo() { return 5; }
}

public class C : A
{
    private B bar = new B();
    public int Foo() { return bar.Foo(); } // no public method Foo on B.
}
```